# Basic access Auth Enable in Azure Application gateway for URL

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-application-gateway

In Nginx, we can set up basic auth by adding annotation in the ingress.

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: Authentication Required
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: basic-auth
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
```

But if we are using azure application gateway instead of Nginx how can we set up basic auth.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately **Azure Application Gateway** doesn't support **basic auth** and I would say using an **ingress controller** like **nginx-ingress** is the proper choice in a scenario where you need this feature. The lack of support for authentication in **Azure Application Gateway** was already reported in [this thread](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/19473664-authentication-support-for-application-gateway).